# Calling JQuery's html() function twice in one method does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to replace the contents of two table rows on a button click. I attempted this using JQuery's [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/), but I cannot seem to call that function twice in the same method call. I tested the following in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7swbx413/):

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='textToReplace'>I want to be replaced with an input!</td>
      <td class='theButton'><input type="button" id="test" value="make editable"/></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', "#test", function(e) {
   $(e.target).closest("td").html('<input type="button" value="cancel edit"/>');
   $(e.target).closest("tr").find('td.textToReplace').html('<input type="text" value="I am now editable!"/>');
});
```

Please note that in practice the table I'm working with will be an unknown number of rows, which is why I'm using classes and jquery selectors to drill through the dom. Either line of the method works fine in isolation, but in trying to call both, it will only execute the first line. Is there a restriction on calling .html() or am I simply missing something?

Comment: You can call `.html()` as many times as you want, but if it updates the content of the *same element* twice, only the second change will have any effect (obviously). *edit* oh also what SLaks said :)

Comment: Try if these contain something (after the first call to `html()`): `$(e.target)`, `$(e.target).closest("tr")`, `$(e.target).closest("tr").find('td.textToReplace')` (set a breakpoint or type "debugger;" into the function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.html()` replaces the entire DOM subtree with new elements parsed from the HTML.

This means that the old subtree, including `e.target`, is no longer in the document and is has no such ancestor.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Simply change the order

```
$(document).on('click', "#test", function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest("tr").find('td.textToReplace').html('<input type="text" value="I am now editable!"/>');
  $(e.target).closest("td").html('<input type="button" value="cancel edit"/>');
});
```

2) Set the parent element before changing the dom:

```
$(document).on('click', "#test", function(e) {
  var elem = $(e.target).closest("tr");
  $(e.target).closest("td").html('<input type="button" value="cancel edit"/>');
  $(elem).find('td.textToReplace').html('<input type="text" value="I am now editable!"/>');
});
```

Comment: Setting the parent element before calling .html() sounds like a good plan. Thanks.